# Django template table format

Tags: django, django-templates

As I iterate results. There are rows that can be merged, however, relative columns will have multiple rows.

For example: 
Currently:

```
Domain ID----sub Domain Title---- Sub domain ID

A1-----------------A1 title-----------A1.1

A1-----------------A1 title-----------A1.2
```

I would like it to be like this. With first two columns with merged rows

```
Domain ID----sub Domain Title---- Sub domain ID

A1----------------A1 title------------A1.1

---------------------------------------- A1.2

<table class="table table-sm">
        <tr>
            <th>Domain ID</th>
            <th>Sub Domain title</th>
            <th>Sub domain ID</th>
        </tr>
        {% for record in a6titles %}
        <tr>
            <td>A6</td>
            <td>A6 title</td>
            <td>titles: {{ record }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<table class="table table-sm">
        <tr>
            <th>Domain ID</th>
            <th>Sub Domain title</th>
            <th>Sub domain ID</th>
        </tr>
        {% for record in a6titles %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan=3>A6</td>
            <td>titles: {{ record }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </table>
```